# How to create a redirect to an html file in a php condition on symfony?

Tags: php

how to create a redirect to an html file in a php condition on symfony please?
I want that if the counter is greater than 4 there is a redirection to an html page.

```
if (count > 4){
// Redirect html file  (add html file example.html.twig)
}
```

Comment: Try this 
`header("Location: anotherDirectory/anotherFile.php");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
if (count > 4){
$script = "<script> window.location = 'example.html.twig';</script>";
echo $script;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to render a html twig template from symfony you can use the following in your Controller:

```
  return $this->render('index.html.twig');
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#rendering-a-template-in-controllers

If you want to redirect to an external URL:

```
return $this->redirect('http://stackoverflow.com');
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#redirecting